# I got this error when google play testing my app

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console, google-console-developer

my app created by react native , when Im uploaded it to google play console for an alpha test , the console show me this error :

> java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: debug cert rejected

repeated 300 time

I don't understand what does it mean ? and what to do !
my app works fine in all devices this error shown only when console test it on  samsung Galaxy S9 , android 8  .

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same exception when testing my kotlin app on the Play console. Inspecting at the sequence of screenshots, the random robot tried to share a document in Google drive just before the crash.

I suspect the tester robot does not have a proper Google account and the crash comes from there but not from your app.